# Is it Possible to Recover Data from a BLACKHOLE table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, storage-engine

I had created table with engine **BLACKHOLE**  basically the BLACKHOLE storage engine acts as a “black hole” that accepts data but throws it away and does not store it. Retrievals always return an empty result.

I heard that we can retrieve the data by creating a new table same as the old table with storage engine as innodb or myisam. but i had tried that also but unable to get the result. Can any one pl help me on this issue to fix it.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test1(i INT, c CHAR(10)) ENGINE = BLACKHOLE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(1,'record one'),(2,'record two');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  CREATE TABLE test_recovery as select * from test1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE test_recovery ENGINE = innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


mysql> SELECT * FROM test_recovery;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Nothing can come out of a black hole, not even light. That's why they were named this way.

Comment: @ypercube there is no way to get data's of that??

Comment: @ypercube What about Hawking radiation? And what about point in time recovery with bin logs?

Comment: @jynus Hawking radiation is a tiny amount of energy compared to what comes into the hole. As for point in time recovery, that's like reconstructing the universe, still nothing is taken from the back hole itself ;)

Comment: What about the MySQLWormhole engine? That way you could travel back in time and retrieve your data **before** it enters the MySQLBlackhole!

Comment: @Vérace i had tried by altering engine to wormhole but unable to get data..

Comment: Are you running on Unix? The data might be in /dev/null

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the impossible. As user and [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) states "The BLACKHOLE storage engine acts as a “black hole” that accepts data but throws it away and does not store it. Retrievals always return an empty result"

Comment: Boring! Facts. Worse still, backed up with credible references to actual documentation (very unsporting behaviour). This thread has clearly degenerated into complete silliness - perfect for a Friday afternoon! :-)

Comment: A second point - as Napoléon [clearly](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_n'est_pas_fran%C3%A7ais) stated in 1808, "Impossible n'est pas français". So, if it's not impossible for the inventor of the metric system and most of the world's legal frameworks, it clearly can't be impossible for MySQL. QED, or as the French would say, CQFD!

Comment: @Vérace Yes, but the little corporal also said "I think I'll invade Russia"

Comment: Perhaps the title should really be `Is it Possible to Recover Data from a BLACKHOLE table ?` or `Why Can Data Not Be Recovered from a BLACKHOLE table ?` or put `If the Data is Gone, Why Can Data Not Be Recovered from a BLACKHOLE table ?` into the Question.

Answer (score 13):

You said

> I heard that we can retrieve the data by creating a new table same as the old table with storage engine as innodb or myisam

Whoever told you that should have told you to enable binary logs as @jynus commented.

The [BLACKHOLE Storage Engine does not store data at all](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html). It is a special storage engine used in very meticulous setups.

## EXAMPLE #1 : Star Topology

Some have Star Topologies to write data to a MySQL Replication Master. The Master has nothing but BLACKHOLE tables. All Slaves have InnoDB or MyISAM. That way, if the Master gets hacked, there is no local data. Such a Master is known as a Distribution Master.

- `Apr 28, 2011` : [**MySQL in star topology (ServerFault)**](https://serverfault.com/a/270255/69271)
- `Mar 11, 2011` : [**MySQL in star topology (StackOverflow)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784578/491757)

## EXAMPLE #2 : Single Slave, Multiple Masters

This involves setting up Circular Replication with three servers. Two Masters with a mix of BLACKHOLE tables and a Slave with all real tables. This technique predates multisource replication.

- `Apr 18, 2013` : [Single slave - multiple master MySQL replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/single-slave-multiple-master-mysql-replication/40382#40382)
- `May 16, 2011` : [Is Multi Master Single Slave possible in mySQL DB? (ServerFault)](https://serverfault.com/a/270255/69271)

## EXAMPLE #3 : Increase Write Performance

I knew of a Web Hosting Client who went to Percona for performance issues on one table. Since the client had MySQL Replication with Multiple Slaves, Percona converted the problem table to BLACKHOLE. This increased write performance on the Master. The data had to be read from the Slaves.

I once suggested this in a post for recording audit information ([Performance of a Trigger vs Stored Procedure in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/performance-of-a-trigger-vs-stored-procedure-in-mysql/4647#4647))

## EPILOGUE

While some of the comments remind me of StarTrek DS9, the BLACKHOLE Storage Engine is what its name says: *NO DATA IS EVER STORED* !!! If you had binary logs enabled, that would have been your only chance of having data.

Comment: since when were facts and technicalities involved in this question? :)

Comment: Isn't it great that we can be techies (or even, perhaps, nerds), without being propeller headed dweebs! +1

Comment: Of course, if binlogging is enabled... the data *is* actually all there if the logs haven't been purged, and there *is* a possibility of recovering it by replaying them from just the right point on another system.