# replication filtering replicate-rewrite and do-table Mysql 5.6 (innodb engine )

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

I have a master/slave replication setup based on statement based replication.
On master database named DB1, I have 5 tables and I want to replicate only two table on slave's database named DB2.

Also, I want to change the database name on my slave end.

So my configuration file on Slave end look like this and replication filtering is this:

```
   replicate-rewrite-db="DB1->DB2"
   replicate-do-table=DB2.table4
   replicate-do-table=DB2.table5
```

Also I have tried below filtering as well:

```
   replicate-rewrite-db="DB1->DB2"
   replicate-do-table=DB1.table4
   replicate-do-table=DB1.table5
```

But in both case records not getting replicated , also no error is reporting.

As per MySQL documentation , replicate-rewrite-db doesn't work with replicate-do-table.

Any method to resolve this? Or is this not possible?

I'm using MySQL 5.6 community edition on Linux server.

I haven't made any changes to master end as it is on customer side.

Comment: Please don't use BLACKHOLE storage engine : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73502/is-it-possible-to-recover-data-from-a-blackhole-table/73521#73521

Comment: im using innodb engine...@RolandoMySQLDBA i expect a solution from you , i know you can suggest me something

Comment: Have you tries ignoring other table? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-ignore-table

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db) that you cannot use table level filtering on replication.
You might like to try another approach instead. 
Replicate whole database and change all tables except those you need to use to `BLACKHOLE` engine.

`alter table X engine=BLACKHOLE;`

Comment: Sir , im using innodb..

Comment: What I'm suggesting here is because you will not be able to filter replication as well as rewrite to new database... you can choose a "hack"...
1. Specify "replicate-rewrite-db" and let everything replicate. This way you will be able to replicate to different database.
2. Change the engine of tables that you  don't want to  replicate to BLACKHOLE. This way you will not storing the data of those tables.

I hope I'm clear here!

Comment: I just noted @ronaldoMySQLDBA's comment about "not using BLACKHOLE" but here your sole purpose is to ignore that data. 
Unless there is a way I missed about mixing replicate-rewrite-db with replicate-do-table this is the only way I can think of.

Comment: There is another but messy way I wouldn't suggest but just  sharing..
1. Use replicate-rewrite-db
2. Drop tables that you don't need
3. Igonre replication errors generated due to those missing tables.. may be using pt-slave-restart or using slave-skip-errors... Which is even more riskier!! [Don't use this ;)]

Comment: hmmm..but both risky ..isn't ?

Comment: You don't want to replicate tables but with available situation this is not possible. So you're replicating all tables and discarding data of some (which you don't need).

When you set BLACKHOLE engine on slave, you don't store data for those tables. This is not risky if you really intend not to keep that data!!

Comment: okay !! but this is not a solution..its a work around

Comment: ...because what you're asking is not allowed in MySQL, you need to do a,  "work-around". Until MySQL supports this request I'm afraid this work-around is the solution for you.

Comment: yeah i do understand this..thank you for your support mysql_user